# Use GzipCompressionProviderOptions in Middlewear ,Bearer was not authenticated

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I tried to use

```
> GzipCompressionProviderOptions
```

in service Middleware, and get the error message:

> "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:
>   Information: Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: No
>   SecurityTokenValidator available for token: undefined."

this is my configuration in Middlewware :

```
        ////Configure Compression level
        services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest);

        //Add Response compression services
        services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        });
```

and in Configure :

```
app.UseResponseCompression();
```

if I delete the configuration, then the registration Bearer managed and will created.
does anyone know why this could happen. thanks.

**UPDATE :**

This my Configuration JWtBearer In Middleware ConfigureService :

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            RSAParameters keyParams = RSAKeyUtils.GetKeyParameters("issuerToken.json");
            key = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey(keyParams);
            tokenOptions = new TokenAuthOptions()
            {
                Audience = TokenAudience,
                Issuer = TokenIssuer,
                SigningCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(key, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature)
            };}

and : 

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            var tokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = key,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = TokenIssuer,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = TokenAudience,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(600)
            };

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
            });

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
                CookieName = "access_token",
                CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Index",
                LoginPath = "/AuthMember",
                LogoutPath = "/Home",
                Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
                    {
                        if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        }
                        else if (ctx.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        }
                        else if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        }
                        else if (ctx.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        }
                        else if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                        }
                        else if (ctx.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        }
                        else if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                        }
                        else if (ctx.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you please provide how you configured JwtBearer ?